# Quarkus application not able run Docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile, quarkus

New to quarkus. need to understand why quarkus is not able to get the argument provided in entrypoint.

Passing some arguemnts but after deploying the appliaction quarkus is not picking up arguments which configure to it on vargroups k8s.

**ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "/deployments/quarkus-run.jar","--mp.messaging.incoming.issues-in.topic=${KAFKA_IN_TOPIC}","--mp.messaging.outgoing.payload-out.topic=${KAFKA_OUT_TOPIC}" ]**

After deploying in k8s not able to get in_tpoic and out_topic.

Really appreciate your support!

Comment: Where are `KAFKA_IN_TOPIC` and `KAFKA_OUT_TOPIC` defined. Also, have you tried without `--` ?

Comment: Hello, doesn't seem clear to me, are your KAFKA_IN_TOPIC and KAFKA_OUT_TOPIC not set correctly in this context ? or is Quarkus not able to get them ?

Comment: @jacouille everything is set correctly but Quarkus is not able to get it from Dockerfile.jvm

Comment: @geoand KAFKA_IN_TOPIC and KAFKA_OUT_TOPIC is declare inside k8s vargroup. And tried with -D as well as removing -- both way not working

Comment: @geoand any solution for this kind issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for this issue: Quarkus application need pass argument in below sequence

> ENTRYPOINT [ "java",
> "-Dmp.messaging.incoming.issues-in.topic=${KAFKA_IN_TOPIC}",jar",
> "/deployments/quarkus-run.jar"]